# tfs test execution states - can we add additional statuses

Tags: testing, tfs

This question is regards to whether or not additional test execution statuses can be added to TFS.

Out of the box, when running tests the tests can either Pass, fail, Blocked, or N/A/  I would like to add a "Caution" status as well - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to customize the test result values and add a failure type. It is possible.

The test result is **associated with MTM**. If you want to customize Test Result Failure Type & Resolution Type, please refer the link from MSDN: [Customize and manage the test experience [tcm and Microsoft Test Manager]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398070.aspx)

More info, please take a look at this uservoice: *[Provide customization for test plan, test results](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2039013-provide-customization-for-test-plan-test-results)*.

> *For customizing Test Result Failure Type & Resolution Type, we have added this capability in VS 2012 Update#2. Take a look at:*
>
> *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398070.aspx*
>
> *http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/05/microsoft-test-manager-customization-of-test-result-fields-and-marking-test-results-as-na.aspx*